# how to make breakpoints stop in my application's code in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, debugging, pycharm

I am new to python and django. I have a project, **myforum**, that uses an application askbot (with some customization). In Pycharm, I open 2 folders, myforum, askbot-devel, in the same project window.

I install askbot with

`python setup.py develop`.

It installs askbot as a link under site-packages of my python runtime:
[image]

if I set a breakpoint in myforum's code and run server in debug mode, the program will stop at the breakpoint. But if I set a breakpoint in an askbot's code, e.g. writers.py, the program still doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

How can I make the program stop at the breakpoint in askbot's code?